# Bootstrap wrapper class that imports minified bootstrap css file?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, web-essentials

I've run into a rather annoying issue.

We have a very large code base which is mostly legacy code, and we have just begun implementing bootstrap. We have to "namespace" or "wrap" the bootstrap code in a class so that we can apply bootstrap to only parts of a page without affecting anything else.

If you're familiar with this technique, the common workaround is this:

```
.bootstrap-wrapper {
    @import (less) "bootstrap.css";
}
```

See this issue: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1709

This works great as long as `bootstrap.css` is not minified. For whatever reason (probably something to do with semicolons), the minified version is not valid less even though it is valid css, and the less compiler errors out.

This wouldn't be much of an issue, except we are using Web Essentials (for VS 2013 update 4) to automatically compile our less into minified css files, and there is no granularity whatsoever.

We have the option to compile the unminified css files turned off, because we have no use for them, and only need the minified files. Since Web Essentials is all or nothing, there's no way for me to compile the unminified file in just this one case. We would have to carry an extra css file for every single compiled less file just to support this one case.

Are there any alternatives to creating a wrapper class this way, or is there anything I can do with Web Essentials to make this work?

Comment: Indeed, that's a difficult one. In general I'd suggest some [`ccscomb`](https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb) to unminify it, but I guess you won't be able to hook it there (otherwise you would just turn minification off for that particular file). No good ideas so far. And no, there's no other wrapping methods.

Comment: Ah, by the way - I've just tested "bootstrap.min.css" `v3.3.4` (the one from their release) and it's compiled by `lessc` `v2.5.0` w/o error. Could you try these versions? (of course your minified version may differ in some details but in general it seems to be possible.. maybe after some fine-tuning, I don't know what is the current Less version included with the WE though...).

Comment: @seven-phases-max The "bootstrap.min.css" taken straight from the v3.3.4 release did work. Unfortunately, I need to be able to customize it, and I'm limited to the less.js compiler and the minification that web essentials uses.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Using web essentials to compile the v3.3.4 bootstrap.less and minify it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you could try to update just the minifier? (e.g. `clean-css` - I suspect the actual problem is at its part, afaik it should not be a problem to update the one shipped with WE (after all these tools installed with WE are just plain classic node modules)).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I narrowed it down to the less compiler. I used the bootstrap.css shipped with v3.3.4, and minified it using web essentials, and it worked. Unless I'm mistaken, WE is using the "node-less" node module for the less compiler. This is located at https://github.com/EdwonLim/node-less and hasn't been updated in 2 years. The problem with manually changing the node modules is that we would have to keep it up to date manually, and do it on every developer's machine.

Comment: @seven-phases-max nm, after looking in the extension folder it looks like it's using the official less module, but version 2.1.0, even though it claims to always be running the latest version.

Comment: Just in case what is the exact error message? Sure it would be handy to track down the exact offender there, could be: particular Less version, particular minifier version, some of your specific BS customizations. Depending on this the solution may come a bit easier to find.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I took out all of my customization and tried compiling and minifying just the v3.3.4 bootstrap.less, which did not work. I got this error: "Unrecognised input. Possibly missing opening '{'". I then took the already compiled v3.3.4 boostrap.css from their dist folder and just ran the WE minify on it. The bootstrap.min.css from that worked. So it seems to reason that it's the less compiler that WE is using. I looked in the folder where the WE extension is installed, and it's using the correct node module (less), but version 2.1.0 instead of the latest (2.5.0)

Comment: Even though they claim to always be using the latest less compiler. That would imply they update the node modules every time visual studio starts or something, but it clearly isn't.

Comment: i understand your issue with the minified CSS. But why can't you import bootstrap.less?

Comment: @BassJobsen when you define a namespace and import actual less code inside of it (`.bootstrap-wrapper`), the behavior is more complex than what is intended, which is just to prepend `.bootstrap-wrapper` to all selectors. I think it mostly has to do with the `&` operator, but I'm not entirely sure. You can read up on it in the link I posted in my question. The workaround where you import the .css file instead, you are importing the already compiled css, but telling the compiler to treat it as less, so that it parses it and prepends `.bootstrap-wrapper` to all selectors.

Comment: @seven-phases-max After looking at the current state of WE, I will definitely be scrapping this workflow. WE is getting rid of compiler support in VS 2015 in favor of grunt/gulp, but they admit the main reason is they can't offer the flexibility necessary to keep up with nodejs tooling like compilers. It seems they have already given up on this. I'm now stuck in the middle of a transition, where the nodejs environment will be built into VS 2015, but is too complex to setup on each developer machine in VS 2013 to fully rely on. Cant rely on all developers who may change one line of css to do it

Comment: well i understand now. Personally i should choose an other strategy to migrate to bootstrap. When you inspect the bootstrap.less file you will see that it is already split up in different components and modules. Import only what you need and import bootstrap's mixins using the `(reference)` for the mixins. Or reference all and extend your current classes with those from bootstrap. Could you give some example of the parts your are starting with? Importing all Bootstrap's code for some parts seems a lot of overhead

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506372/bootstrap-list-group-in-foundation-5/30012726 (same for less as for sass)

Comment: @BassJobsen We aren't trying to use *some* of bootstrap *everywhere*. We are trying to use *all* of bootstrap in *some* places. We need to keep it completely isolated at first. We have so many pages, and also have a multi-tenancy structure with different styles for different clients. For instance, we are starting by making the header, which includes the toolbar/nav, fully bootstrap, while the individual page's content is legacy. Eventually, when we have time to rewrite most of the ui, and become more comfortable/familiar/clear on what we are doing with bootstrap, we will get rid of the wrapper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77356/discussion-between-bass-jobsen-and-wired-in).

Comment: @BassJobsen we can't afford to take the chance that even one or two pieces of bootstrap, if implemented globally, would cause unforeseen changes to any of our 1000's of pages, across 100's of clients.